# jogar dados de login no parâmetro da API

Tags: php, javascript, banco-de-dados, json, api

No login eu peço para o usuário colocar o email e cpf, aí tenho uma api que joga dados numa tabela que eu criei, aí eu preciso pegar os parâmetros cpf e email para colocar na api.

**Ex:**

`http://8080/rest/apiCODCPF=02798477425&EMAIL=fulano%40fulano.com.br`

Como consigo pegar os dados de email e cpf e jogar como parâmetro na api?

***Eu só tenho o link da api, não tenho mais nada***

Código pra mostrar os dados da api:

```
    function load(){

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost/r/TRCKCLI?CODCPF=12345678901&EMAIL=fulano%40email.com");



  xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
      var resposta = xhr.responseText;
      // console.log("ola1");
      var clientes = JSON.parse(resposta);
      // console.log("ola2");
      // console.log(clientes);

      for (var i =0; i < 1; i++){
          // console.log("ola3");
         var clientes_1 = clientes.TRACKER[i];
         AdicionaNome(clientes_1);
         AdicionaCPF(clientes_1);
         AdicionaProduto(clientes_1);
         AdicionaCidade(clientes_1);
         AdicionaCodigoProduto(clientes_1);
         AdicionaCodigoCliente(clientes_1);
         AdicionaStatus(clientes_1);
         ActiveStatusImage(clientes_1);
         ActiveOnlyPostagem(clientes_1);
         adicionaClienteNaTabelaViagem(clientes_1);
         ActiveQtdViagem(clientes_1);


     }

  });

  xhr.send();
      }
      window.onload = load;
```

Comment: Essa API você que criou? Alguém criou e falou para você consumir ela? Caso seja de terceiro você tem que saber como é a forma de consurmir: GET/POST, no que você passou seria via GET. Outro detalhe, o link está assim: 'http://8080/rest/apiCODCPF', não seria 'http://nomedolocal:8080/rest/api/', pode ver que colocar o nome do localdaapi e uma barra após a palavra API.

Comment: Exatamente, criaram e mandaram eu consumir ela

Comment: Completei meu comentário acima...

Comment: O link que eu coloquei da api é modificada, só um exemplo, entende? Eu soube consumir ela e mostrar os dados no site, só que preciso colocar cpf e email como parâmetro, como falei na pergunta

Comment: Coloca o código do que você ta tentando...

Comment: Pronto. Desse jeito é como consigo mostrar a api no site (dados da api)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70273/discussion-between-max-rogerio-and-nazare-lisboa).

Answer (score 1):

Se for neste formato utilize:

```
$email = $_GET['EMAIL'];
$cpf   = $_GET['apiCODCPF'];
```

Comment: E eu jogo isso onde?

Comment: No arquivo para onde aponta a URL. O email e CPF estão sendo passados como GET

Comment: Que no caso é onde eu adiciono a API?

Comment: Você coloca no servidor:      cliente -> requisição(GET) ->servidor

Comment: Desculpe, mas não estou entendendo

Comment: Estude um pouco mais sobre arquitetura de API's no estilo REST

Comment: Certo. Mas para fazer isso que voce falou eu preciso ter acesso a api? pq eu só tenho o link dela, entende?